# How to drill back up a folder in Dired?

Tags: dired

In Dired, I'm able to drill down folders with the key `i`, but how can I unfold a folder that was once opened, that is, go to its parent folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What did you try?

`C-h m` tells you about the current mode for an Emacs buffer. In Dired it lists the key bindings, including `^`, which takes you to the parent directory, in Dired.

`C-h k ^` tells you:

> `^` runs the command `dired-up-directory` (found in `dired-mode-map`), which
>   is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `dired.el`.
>
> It is bound to `^`, `<menu-bar> <subdir> <up>`.
>
> `(dired-up-directory &optional OTHER-WINDOW)`
>
> Run Dired on parent directory of current directory.
>
> Find the parent directory either in this buffer or another buffer.
>   Creates a buffer if necessary.
>   If `OTHER-WINDOW` (the optional prefix arg), display the parent
>   directory in another window.

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then `^` is this instead:

> `^` runs the command `diredp-up-directory` (found in `dired-mode-map`),
>   which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> It is bound to `^`, `menu-bar subdir navigate up`.
>
> `(diredp-up-directory &optional OTHER-WINDOW)`
>
> Run Dired on parent directory of current directory.
>
> Find the parent directory either in this buffer or another buffer.
>   Creates a buffer if necessary.
>
> With a prefix arg, Dired the parent directory in another window.
>
> On MS Windows, if you are already at the root directory, invoke
>   `diredp-w32-drives` to visit a navigable list of Windows drives.

---

But since you mention `i` and drilling down in the sense of showing a subdirectory listing, maybe you are asking (also?) how to get back to the parent directory listing from a subdirectory listing.  `^` also does that.

With Dired+, you can alternatively use `i` again, with the cursor on a file in the subdir listing or on the subdir header line (but not with the cursor on a subdir in the subdir listing - in that case that subdir is itself listed).

In other words, `i` toggles back and forth between parent and child directory.

In vanilla Dired (not Dired+), `i` does not toggle this way.  You need to use `^` to go to the parent listing.

---

You can also show/hide a subdir listing using `$`. And you can remove all listings other than the main one with `C-x C-v`.